# Best way to add / remove a field from all queries

Tags: aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

We have a condition that affects all queries, lets say:

```
field: "CONDITION"
```

When we try to remove this field from all queries, DocumentDB CPU spikes and stays high, even after cache index / buffer hit ratio go back to almost 100%.

"field" is not part of any index, and it does not make any sense that removing it from query would destroy performances that much.

Any insights on what we are doing wrong ?

When rolling it back, it instantly goes back to normal, even if we roll back 4-5 hours later.

Comment: What is the "condition"? Can you post the exact query/operation that you are doing? Also examining the output of [explain()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/user_diagnostics.html#user_diagnostics-query_plan) may give you more insight.